# failed assertion, no message given: rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, railstutorial.org

I have been working through Hartl's RoR tutorial and have been stuck at this section for a while. I am trying to run the account activation test with:

```
$ bundle exec rake test
```

I end up getting this out put:

```
1) Failure:
    UsersSignupTest#test_valid_signup_information_with_account_activation     [/Users/*name/blogger1/test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:44]:
Failed assertion, no message given.
```

Here is my test code in my users_signup_test.rb file:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersSignupTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

def setup
  ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.clear
end

test "invalid signup information" do
  get signup_path
  assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
    post users_path, user: { name:  "",
                           email: "user@invalid",
                           password:              "foo",
                           password_confirmation: "bar" }
end
assert_template 'users/new'
assert_select 'div#error_explanation'
assert_select 'div.field_with_errors'
end

test "valid signup information with account activation" do
get signup_path
assert_difference 'User.count', 1 do
  post users_path, user: { name:  "Example User",
                           email: "user@example.com",
                           password:              "password",
                           password_confirmation: "password" }
end
assert_equal 1, ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size
user = assigns(:user)
assert_not user.activated?
# Try to log in before activation.
log_in_as(user)
assert_not is_logged_in?
# Invalid activation token
get edit_account_activation_path("invalid token")
assert_not is_logged_in?
# Valid token, wrong email
get edit_account_activation_path(user.activation_token, email: 'wrong')
assert_not is_logged_in?
# Valid activation token
get edit_account_activation_path(user.activation_token, email: user.email)
assert user.reload.activated?
follow_redirect!
assert_template 'users/show'
assert is_logged_in?
end
end
```

When I followed the tutorial I was following the code and typing it in myself. But, this time with all the issues I went back and copy and pasted it. Any ideas on what it could be?

Line 44 is:

```
assert user.reload.activated?
```

But I couldn't find anything that was relatable anywhere else?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem yesterday, the problem is not on the test but it's on the 'activated?' method itself that doesn't works properly.

I found the solution by tracing back the 'activated?' method for typing errors, which in my case I found it in create_activation_digest method on User model.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue and solved it.
In my case, the cause was missing log_in(user) method in AccountActivationsController.

Please make sure that you log in successfully-activated users in AccountActivationsController.

```
class AccountActivationsController < ApplicationController

  def edit
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    if user && !user.activated? && user.authenticate_with_token(:activation, params[:id])
      user.activate
      **log_in user**
      flash[:success] = "Account activated!"
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Invalid activation link"
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
end
```

Michael Hartl's [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/)

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you change the boolean in the authenticated? method to: `return false if digest.nil?`. My error stemmed from that.